# Как сделать чтобы рисунок передвигался а не растягивался?

Tags: c#, sfml

Всем привет. Суть задания отрисовать косинус и синус, чтобы можно было стрелочками передвигать влево вправо вверх вниз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random();
        static List<Color> colors = new List<Color>(new Color[] 
        { 
            Color.Black, 
            Color.Blue, 
            Color.Cyan, 
            Color.Green, 
            Color.Magenta, 
            Color.Red, 
            Color.White, 
            Color.Yellow 
        });

        static Color GetRandomColor()
        {
            var item = colors[random.Next(0, colors.Count)];
            return item;
        }

        static VertexArray GetVertexArray(float scale, float offset, float lambda)
        {
            VertexArray vertexArray = new VertexArray(PrimitiveType.LineStrip);
            for (float i = 0; i < 10 * Math.PI; i += 0.05f)
            {
                vertexArray.Append(new Vertex(new Vector2f(i * lambda, (float)Math.Cos(i) * scale + offset), GetRandomColor()));
            }
            return vertexArray;
        }

        static VertexArray GetVertexArraySin(float scale, float offset, float lambda)
        {
            VertexArray vertexArray = new VertexArray(PrimitiveType.LineStrip);
            for (float i = 0; i < 10 * Math.PI; i += 0.05f)
            {
                vertexArray.Append(new Vertex(new Vector2f(i * lambda, (float)Math.Sin(i) * scale + offset)));
            }
            return vertexArray;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float y = 300;
            float lambda = 50;
            RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800, 600), "Окно");

            window.Closed += Window_Closed;
            window.MouseButtonPressed += Window_MouseButtonPressed;
            window.KeyPressed += Window_KeyPressed;

            window.Clear();
            window.Draw(GetVertexArray(50, y, lambda));
            window.Draw(GetVertexArraySin(50, y, lambda));
            window.Display();

            while (window.IsOpen)
            {
                window.WaitAndDispatchEvents();

                if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Up))
                {
                    y -= 10;
                    window.Clear();
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArray(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArraySin(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Display();
                }

                if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Down))
                {
                    y += 10;
                    window.Clear();
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArray(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArraySin(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Display();
                }

                if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Left))
                {
                    lambda--;
                    window.Clear();
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArray(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArraySin(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Display();
                }

                if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Right))
                {
                    lambda++;
                    window.Clear();
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArray(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArraySin(50, y, lambda));
                    window.Display();
                }

                if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Space))
                {
                    window.Clear();
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArray(50, 300, 50));
                    window.Draw(GetVertexArraySin(50, 300, 50));
                    window.Display();
                }

                if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Escape))
                {
                    window.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Window_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Code);
            //if (e.Code == Keyboard.Key.Escape) Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private static void Window_MouseButtonPressed(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ e.Button }, { e.X }, { e.Y }");
        }

        private static void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Мой код. Из скринов видно, особенно на 2, что стрелочка влево просто сжимает рисунок а не двигает, как сделать так, чтобы рисунок не сжимался а просто двигался влево?
И ещё вопрос как сделать сплошной цвет линии? Т.е не разноцветный

Comment: Это точно ваш код? Если вам не нужны разные цвета, то зачем вы их добавляли? Если вы их добавляли, то почему не можете убрать? Вы свой код то хоть сами читали?

Comment: Код не мой, цвета убрал совсем, сейчас белые линии.

Comment: Осталось понять, почему в контрукции типа `new Vector2f(i * lambda, (float)Math.Sin(i) * scale + offset)` есть смещение только по вертикали и как добавить его по горизонтали.